# Why vertical line is not completely connected from top to bottom?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want top and bottom lines to be dark line.

```
    \PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
    \documentclass[paper=legapaper,9pt]{scrartcl}              %class
    \usepackage[left=1.0cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} %for layout
    \usepackage{setspace} % for spacing between lines
    \usepackage{graphicx}         %for including images
    \usepackage{eso-pic}     %package for including background image
    \usepackage{color,tikz}
    \usepackage{wallpaper}
    \usepackage{ulem}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{calligra}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{niceframe}
    \usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \newboolean{long}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \usepackage{eurosym,datatool,longtable,booktabs}


    \begin{document}


       \begin{tabular}{l|ccccc|c|c|c|ccc}
         \toprule

         \bfseries Exams. Passed & &&\bfseries Name of &&  &\bfseries Examination  & \bfseries Year of  & \bfseries Division/  & &\bfseries Name of& \\ 
         &&& \bfseries Board/University &&& \bfseries Roll No. & \bfseries Passing & \bfseries Class && \bfseries School/College&\\ \toprule
         H.S.L.C. &&&&&  & &  &  & &&\\ \hline
         H.S.S.L.C. &&&&&  & &  &  &&& \\ \hline
         B.A/B.Sc./B.Com/L.L.B & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\ 
         B.E/M.B.B.S/B.Mus. &&&&&  & &  &  & &&\\ \hline
         M.A/M.Sc./M.Com. & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\ \hline 
         Others & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\
         \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Try removing the blank line at the top of the table, after the `\toprule`. Also, the second `\toprule` should probably be `\midrule`. It is likely that you will still be unhappy with the output because `\toprule` and friends do not play well with vertical lines in tables. Indeed, the opening pages of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual strongly recommends against using them! Personally, I think that the table looks better without them. If you really want the vertical lines then use `\hline` and drop [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) from your preamble.

Comment: it is still the same not connecting. If i remove booktabs package then toprule command not working. @Andrew

Comment: Booktabs is not meant to work with vertical lines. Try to google something like "Beautiful tables in LaTeX" or "LaTeX table design recommendations". I think that you will find that everybody advises against vertical lines. The grid type of tables comes from excel and people who do not know better.

Comment: `booktabs` has something like \aboveruleskip, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your table setup (with and without use of `booktabs`). I just rotated the tables to make them fit your page. But you should consider the following:

- the advice given in the `booktabs` manual
- your table has two rows for the title (maybe you should use a `p{}` based solution that centers)
- probably if you use those vertical rules you should also make them close the left and right side of the table

[image: tables]

Code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[paper=legapaper,9pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
   \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{l|ccccc|c|c|c|ccc}
     \hline
     \bfseries Exams. Passed & &&\bfseries Name of &&  &\bfseries Examination  & \bfseries Year of  & \bfseries Division/  & &\bfseries Name of& \\ 
     &&& \bfseries Board/University &&& \bfseries Roll No. & \bfseries Passing & \bfseries Class && \bfseries School/College&\\ \hline
     H.S.L.C. &&&&&  & &  &  & &&\\ \hline
     H.S.S.L.C. &&&&&  & &  &  &&& \\ \hline
     B.A/B.Sc./B.Com/L.L.B & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\ 
     B.E/M.B.B.S/B.Mus. &&&&&  & &  &  & &&\\ \hline
     M.A/M.Sc./M.Com. & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\ \hline 
     Others & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\
     \hline
   \end{tabular}}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{l*{11}{c}}
     \toprule
     \bfseries Exams. Passed & &&\bfseries Name of &&  &\bfseries Examination  & \bfseries Year of  & \bfseries Division/  & &\bfseries Name of& \\ 
     &&& \bfseries Board/University &&& \bfseries Roll No. & \bfseries Passing & \bfseries Class && \bfseries School/College&\\ \midrule
     H.S.L.C. &&&&&  & &  &  & &&\\ \hline
     H.S.S.L.C. &&&&&  & &  &  &&& \\ \hline
     B.A/B.Sc./B.Com/L.L.B & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\ 
     B.E/M.B.B.S/B.Mus. &&&&&  & &  &  & &&\\ \hline
     M.A/M.Sc./M.Com. & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\ \hline 
     Others & &&&& & &  &  & &&\\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```